# Turn on Wi-Fi when a specific message received

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, wifi, android-wifi

I want to enable Wi-Fi and GPS when a SMS "on_location" is received. I make the following code but the applications terminated when the SMS is received. Can you help? Thank you in advance.

```
public class SmsSaveContact extends BroadcastReceiver {
//private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
//private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //abortBroadcast();
    Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage [] messages = null;
    String strMessage = "";

    if (myBundle != null)
    {
        Object [] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");
        messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
        {
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            strMessage += "SMS From: " + messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            strMessage += " : ";
            strMessage += messages[i].getMessageBody();
            //strMessage += "\n";
        }
        if(strMessage.contains("on_location")){
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){

                   wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

                 }else{

                     wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

                   }    
        }
    }
}
```

}

Updated Log Cat:

> 12-24 20:55:47.846: W/dalvikvm(7356): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41805c08)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356): Process: com.example.cameraservice, PID: 7356
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED flg=0x8000010 (has extras) } in com.example.cameraservice.SmsSaveContact@42abde80
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:782)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10373 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub$Proxy.getWifiEnabledState(IWifiManager.java:1174)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.getWifiState(WifiManager.java:1279)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.isWifiEnabled(WifiManager.java:1291)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at com.example.cameraservice.SmsSaveContact.onReceive(SmsSaveContact.java:37)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:772)
>   12-24 20:55:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     ... 9 more

Comment: Post your logcat for a better response.

Comment: @JASONGPETERSON I have updated my question with the logcat. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

in logcat logs :

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10373 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE. 12-24 20:55:47.896:

added receive message permission and wifi-state permission to mainfist.xml file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" /> ?

Comment: Thank you, i have fix it. It was something with the receiver in the manifest

Comment: post your mainfist.xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsSaveContact">

        <intent-filter android:priority="999">

            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

...........

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```